Datetime is aws glue job is not taking the local time-zone, it is using UTC?
I am running an AWS Glue job in ap-south-1 region. Here I have used the python datetime function to load one of my audit columns (created_on). When I tried to load the datetime.now(), it is taking the UTC time-zone, instead of the local time-zone. How to solve this, and why glue is taking the UTC time-zone even though it is hosted in the ap-south-1 region?


One solution is to mention the zone directly in the datetime function as shown below we can define these methods to get the time and date. But this still does not answer why glue jobs datetime.now() is not taking the hosted time zone?
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

def get_current_timestamp():
    utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
    local_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
    return utc_now.astimezone(local_timezone)

def get_current_date():
    utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
    local_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
    return utc_now.astimezone(local_timezone).date()

